# Commit/push project changes without adding configuration files

Tags: git

I have project that has several source files. Usually I don't pay attention which file was modified while programming. And I register changes to server in this way:

```
git add .
git commit - m"msg"
git push
```

This pushes all files that are in my project directory. And I don't like this, because it pushes all configuration files that I don't want place to server.

How to tell git "look yourself which source files was modified , show me if I have new source files and let decide for me I would like to publish them and don't look for other files"

Comment: You should put those configuration files in `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
'git rm --cached name_of_file '
Command. This will ignore the files even if they were added before with ' git add'.
.gitignore ignores just files that weren't tracked before with 'git add'

Comment: This answer is the solution to your problem. This comment points out to a tutorial on how to fix gitignore: https://learningpassion.wordpress.com/2016/06/17/git-tutorial-day-to-day-use-part-4-gitignore-diff-and-difftools-moving-and-removing-files/. You only need to read the gitignore part.

But before using the gitignore, make sure to use `git rm --cached <file>` before.